# add all missing dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've the following data. How can I add all dates (from 1st to the end of the month) ? also how can I remove saturdays and sundays from this dataset?

```
Date        values
31/03/14    -0.0123
30/04/14    0.11168
30/06/14    0.0997
31/07/14    0.007
30/09/14    0.886



Date    values
1/3/14
2/3/14
.....
..
31/3/14
1/4/14
2/4/14
....
.....
30/09/14
```

Comment: please post your desired data set

Comment: @MaxU I've added the required dataset. Basically, I want all dates first then remove all saturdays and sundays if posiibles and then fill ffil/bfill in values. Please let me know if this is possible?

Comment: should your desired data set include data for May and August or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Assuming you can reload your dataset from a csv

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
Date        values
31/03/14    -0.0123
30/04/14    0.11168
30/06/14    0.0997
31/07/14    0.007
30/09/14    0.886'''

# This operation includes reading the dataset, converting Date to Datetime and
# setting Date as index
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data),sep='\s+',parse_dates=['Date'],index_col='Date')

# Resample day
df = df.resample('D').sum()  # or first() or mean() 

# Remove weekdays smaller than 5 (saturday and sunday) and reset
df = df.loc[df.index.weekday < 5].reset_index()

print(df.head())
```

And you get (printing first 5 rows):

```
        Date  values
0 2014-03-31 -0.0123
1 2014-04-01     NaN
2 2014-04-02     NaN
3 2014-04-03     NaN
4 2014-04-04     NaN
```

---

### Assuming you already loaded your dataset

The equivalent assuming you already loaded your dataset (compact). I also added not May or August mask here if you want to exclude those months.

```
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.Date)).drop('Date', axis = 1)
df = df.resample('D').first()
m1 = df.index.weekday < 5          # mask1 (no sat/sun)
m2 = ~df.index.month.isin([5,8])   # mask2 (not May or August)
df = df.loc[m1 & m2].reset_index()
```

Comment: If i understood OP correctly the desired DF should _not_ contain data from May and August...

Comment: @MaxU Yep, it wasn't clear. Maybe OP can clarify later. (added this in the end)

Comment: @MaxU I really appreciate your help! Actually, I don't want saturdays and sundays for the entire dataset not just May and August.

Comment: AWESOME! THis works :) Also, how can I fill the missing values with bffil and ffill?

Comment: @jason Simply add `df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)` or `bfill` and you got a na-fill too.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `date_range`

```
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
s=pd.DataFrame({'Date':sum([pd.date_range(x,y,freq='D').tolist() for x,y in zip(pd.to_datetime(df.Date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')),df.Date)],[])})

s=s.merge(df)
s=s[s.Date.dt.weekday<5]
```